# Including an AAR file conditionally

Tags: android, estimote, aar

I am using the Estimote SDK, which is included into my project as an AAR file.
I want to use the SDK on devices which support Bluetooth LE, but also want to allow users who do not have supported hardware to install.

The manifest of the Estimote SDK includes:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
    android:required="true" />
```

and this prevents the App from installing on a lot of devices.

I can overrule the android:minSdkVersion:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" />
```

with

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.estimote.sdk" />
```

but I don't know how to overrule e.g. the bluetooth_le directive.
I tried unzipping the 'aar', changing the Manifest and repacking as a zip with .aar extension, but I get:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':idoms-android:processIDomsAndroidDevDebugManifest'.
> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/Luuk/Documents/Java/idoms-android/idoms-android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/estimote-sdk-preview/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)
```

even thought the file is there. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Luuk

I'm a author of Estimote Android SDK.

We will be changing `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le">` to `required=false` for the next SDK release .

Answer (score 0):

You should consider creating 2 flavors of your apk, one that has the BLE support and that includes the SDK that you want to use, and another one that doesn't support BLE.

If you create two flavors of your app, let's call them "ble" and "normal", then you are able to declare some flavor-specific dependencies using `bleCompile 'yourDependency'` and `normalCompile 'yourDependency'` in your Gradle build file.

Comment: But does that also mean I need to have two App in the Play! Store?

Comment: I believe it can be published as a single app in the play store even though you have several apks to distribute, you can read more about at http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html